# access zf2 database result object in controller

Tags: database, arrays, controller, zend-framework2, resultset

How can I loop trough my db results in the controller by using a foreach loop?

```
$select = new Select();
$select->from('table_name');
$select->where(array('salt'  => $salt));
$select->where(array('ip'    => $this->_getUserIp()));

$rowset = $this->tableGateway->selectWith($select);

return $rowset;
```

I guess I need to convert the db result object to an array?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zend.db.result-set.html

`Zend\Db\ResultSet\ResultSet` extends `traversable` and therefore you can use `foreach` on it.

```php
foreach($this->getSomeTable()->fetchAll() as $row) {
    //here you can access the row as an array or use getters if you have set a prototype object
    //eg
    $userId = $row['user_id'];
    $userId = $row->user_id;
    $userId = $row->getId();

}
```

Also, I suggest reading through the getting started guide. All this basic stuff is explained there.

http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/user-guide/overview.html

Comment: thanks for the answer, I removed the 'setArrayObjectPrototype' from the module.php right now and this did the trick for me :)